# TCP Socket unable to send data even after executing sendall ()

Tags: python, c++, sockets, tcp, wireshark

Hi I have multiple systems communicating via messages using TCP connections.

In the Process of Communication between the two, I am at first sending a message as "Start Process", for which in return it should reply as "Process Started"

However, the message "Process Started" is not received to the other system, while the line sendall ("Process Started") is executed without any exception.

My sample code is as follows:

TCP Initialisation:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.tcp.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.tcp.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, struct.pack('ll',0,1))
    self.tcp.bind('',12000)
    self.tcp.listen(1)
    self.client, seld.address = self.tcp.accept()
    (self.Ip,self.port)= self.address
```

Main Funciton:

```
while True:
    msg =""
    try:
       msg = self.client.recv(512)
    except socket.error as e:
       if e[0] == 11:
           # exception for RECVTIMEO used in the socket creation.
           pass
    if (msg == "Start Process"):
          send = "Process Started"
          self.client.sendall(send)
          print "status sent"
```

While Executing this piece of code, I am able to receive the message "Start Process". but "Process started" is not sent though on executing the line self.client.sendall(send), I have captured the packets in wireshark, I got the packet containing "Start Process" but No packet obtained for "Process Started"

Can someone help me with this ???

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues, but the one you are struggling with now is that if you connect to port 12000 with telnet and send "Start Process" and hit enter, you will actually send and receive Start Process\n instead of Start Process and your if statement does not match. If you strip the trailing newline, you can mitigate this:

```
try: 
    msg = self.client.recv(512)
    msg = msg.strip()
```

Your program may need some tweaking, though. As you set your socket non-blocking, self.tcp.accept() raises an exception as you try accepting a connection that is not there yet.  The same goes with self.client.recv(), after you have received the correct message. When you add strip, your if clause will match and you will get a response. However, it will just keep responding, as it immediately tries to recv(512) again, fails with an exception, then you catch it and do the if clause again. msg is still "Start Process" as it has not changed (the consecutive recv just failed, it did not return "" or None).

Try moving your if clause inside your try/except construction and only compare msg if you actually have received one.

This program would also be immensely wasteful, as it would be running in a busy loop most of the time, waiting for either connections or messages. If you need to use non-blocking sockets, you would need to address this.

A better way might be using threads to have a blocking thread that listens and accepts new connections, and for every connection it would spawn a worker thread. These threads could then be blocking in recv() until a message is received.

Just a thought.

Hannu

Comment: updated the above mentioned code, I am resetting msg to NULL in the loop. I have not included my other program here in the Question, which is sending "Start Process" to this program later this program is just waiting for the other program to start, with which it binds through TCP and as when it receives "Start Process" it should send "Process Started" , however it is not doing so.

Comment: I did used time.sleep in between recv() and sendall, then it is working, but I am unable to understand the reason for this behavior

Comment: ... and you get the "status sent" printout, confirming sendall() was executed?

Comment: Another issue I didn't flag in your code is that your recv() does not necessarily receive the whole message. It receives whatever is in the receive buffer at the moment of the function call. If you sleep somewhere, you are more likely - but not guaranteed - to receive the whole message instead of just for example first five bytes. In any case, you should build this into your code and somehow ensure you have received an entire message before processing it. Otherwise you might end up comparing "Star" and "t Process" on different iterations, and neither would match.

Comment: yes "staus sent" is obtained, 
The problem which you stated, for that i am using some parsing tags at the starting and at the end as /yyy/ at the starting and /xxx/ at the end, and then checking the received message and splitting it accordingly, I want you to assume that some how I am getting the message. and it is executing sendall(). but still at wireshark it is not able to capture the packets , for similar case when using time.sleep(0.05) before sendall() it is able to send and the packets are captured in wireshark also. I want to understand this behavior

Comment: Interesting.  If you use select.select() on your socket just before sendall to check if the socket is writable, what happens? This wouldn't be too difficult to test.

Comment: interestingly, it is working, and this is directing that the message was not able to send because the pipe was pre-occupied by recv() where it is sending the acknowledgment of the received data... Thanks anyway.

Comment: it is actually waiting for some infinite time for the pipe to ready for some operation or it generate an exception.